# How to acces my Bluetooth source using ADB?

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb, android-bluetooth

I have paired my phone to an android device:

```
1- my paired phone contains several music songs
2- a BT source with all the music of my phone is displayed on the android device
```

Is it possible to access the paired phone source via adb?
If yes how to get the path of my BT source using adb?